# Stimulsoft Report Unicode Character from Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, report, stimulsoft

My Database is Postgresql
and I used `Stimulsoft Report` 
I create a rtf file and type text to **Unicode** and then open this file in preview, but I saw this text `اطلاعات مورد نظر` like this `ÛŒÙˆØ±Ùˆ â‚¬` and changed datatype from `dot-matrix Mode` to `Unicode(UTF-8)` and change font but it has got a error

actually I test `Stimulsoft Report` with `MSSQL` and the result is correct but with `Postgresql`, no! :(

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you are using cracked version from Board4all!!!! Remove the tool from your PC immediately and never use Stimulsoft!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: In my country, it's entirely legal to use cracked software. But I just wanted to test this software and if I wanted to check out this software, I was going to buy it.
Believe me, do not be upset about me

Comment: You are not going to buy, you are already using it. I ask admins to delete this user, since he uses the tool illegally!

Comment: @andrew-savin I downloaded YESTERDAY .... so I think IF I DOWNLOAD AS TRIAL VERSION I COULD USE FOR 30 DAYS .... is it true?
so I tell you IF this app is usefull for me I buy it actually , I told you .. Blive me.

Comment: I does not matter when you downloaded the software. You are using the license key THAT YOU NEVER PURCHASE!

Comment: @andrew-savin
get out me from your black list in telegram and then we solve this problem